# how to control ticklabel_format ofsset

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to use ticklabel_format to change the xticks of my graph,

I have numbers from 0 to 10^6. So I tried ticklabel_format to change to scientific notation, it kinda of work. I was able to change my ticks of 0 - 1000000 to  0 - 1 (1e6).

So I was able to get something like this

```
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='x',style='sci',scilimits=(0,0))
```

I got an image like this

[image]

But when I tried to change `scilimits=(0,3)`, so I could get my xticks from 0 to 1000, and the offset of 1e3, it didn1t work out.

The documentation says that "Scientific notation is used only for numbers outside the range 10m to 10n", so it should change just for number outside (0,1000) right?

If not, could someone tell me how to change it?
And tell me how does it works.